# match other user locations with location of session user?

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to create a mysql statement that selects all users with the same location as the session user. for instance if the person logged in/the session user has manchester listed as their location in the database then i want all users with their location as manchester to be shown to that user.

```
function get_local_users() {
            global $connection;
            global $user_location;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_stats, ptb_users
                        WHERE ptb_stats.user_id = ptb_users.user_id
                        AND ptb_stats.user_location = ".$_SESSION['user_location']."
                        LIMIT 0 , 20";
            $local_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($local_set);
            return $local_set;
        }
```

can someone please show me where i am going wrong as at the minute i am not getting any errors but am also not getting any results. do i need to defined $_SESSION['user_location'] somewhere?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're not quoting the location, so the query is going to look like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE location = manchester;
```

Where it should be:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE location = 'manchester';
```

You could simply add quotes but you should ideally build your query via prepared statements. Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, you should use mysqli_* instead. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/44392-php-5-mysqli-prepared-statements/).

Comment: i understand what your saying however i do not want it to be just manchester, i want it to be compared with the session users location, so whether that be birmingham, london etc so how can i compare it via a session variable?

Comment: Add `echo $query` to your code above so that you can see the actual SQL that's getting run. You'll notice that whatever location gets passed in does not get quoted, and so your SQL is not syntactically valid. I.e., you can pass the variable just like you are, but one way or another, you need to get quotes around it. You can do it manually by explicitly adding quotes to your code, or if you use prepared statements, the quotes will be added automatically for you.